# Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении при инфинитиве

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

1. **Вопрос.** Грамотно ли будет написать:
   "Глядя на них, ему очень захотелось пить"?

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Нет, употребление деепричастного оборота здесь некорректно (т. к. в безличном предложении указан носитель состояния).
Надо перестроить предложение. Например: Глядя на них, он захотел пить.

2. **Вопрос.** Можно ли сказать: 
   "Глядя на него, мне захотелось встать"?
   Или же правильно будет: "При взгляде на него мне захотелось встать"?
   Или: "Глядя на него, я захотел встать"?

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Корректно: Глядя на него, я захотел встать.
Употребление деепричастного оборота в безличном предложении при инфинитиве (Глядя на него, мне захотелось встать) тоже допустимо.

**Так как же правильно?**

Comment: А ваше, doom, мнение о правильности?

Comment: Думаю, допустимо.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** Раньше (в 1982 году) требования к деепричастным  оборотам **были очень строгие:**
а) один и тот же субъект действия для сказуемого и деепричастия;
б) субъект действия должен быть непременно подлежащим (из книги С.Н Цейтлин "Речевые ошибки и их предупреждение").

**2.** В современной академической стилистике (2012 г.) допускается использование деепричастного оборота **в двух случаях:**

**а)** **Это безличное предложение обобщенного характера, где нет указания на конкретного производителя действия (правило, рекомендация, инструкция, сентенция).** В состав такого безличного предложения обязательно должен входить **инфинитив**, например: "Рассматривая данный вопрос, необходимо привлечь все имеющиеся документы".

**б)** Если деепричастный оборот выступает в качестве наречия (обстоятельства образа действия), то есть обозначает **признак** основного действия, а не дополнительное действие, например: Больному разрешено читать сидя в кресле.

**3.** Еще интересно следующее: ошибочные для русского языка конструкции с деепричастными оборотами используются во французском языке, поэтому они иногда **встречаются даже у серьезных писателей 19 века** (их называют **галлицизмы**):
*Проезжая на возвратном пути в первый раз весною знакомую березовую рощу, у меня голова закружилась и забилось сердце от смутного сладкого ожидания* (Тургенев).

**4.** Поэтому безличные предложения с деепричастным оборотом можно разделить на **две группы**:
**Группа 1.** Некорректность выражения очень заметна и поэтому нежелательна.
**Группа 2.** Предложение допускается, так как  на слух воспринимается более или менее нормально.

**Группа 1.**
*Убедившись, что понять этого он не может, ему стало скучно* (Л. Толстой).
*Прочитав внимательно рассказ, мне думается, что редакторских поправок в нем нет* (Горький).

**Группа 2.**
 Глядя на них, ему очень захотелось пить/встать (при взгляде на них).
*Скрываясь в высокой траве, нам удалось добраться незамеченными до самой поляны* (Губарев).
Здесь оборот в роли обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Вера, на одном из сайтов говорится, что т.н. допускаются, если они оправданы замыслом автора. Конечно, в статьях, в рассказах начинающих авторов, лучше избегать таких конструкций.

Comment: Вера, скажите, пожалуйста, автора книги. Может, смогу найти в интернете.

Comment: РАН, Программа "Словари 21 века" Ю.А. Бельчиков "Практическая стилистика современного языка", Москва, 2012 год. А вот идея насчет авторского замысла мне не очень нравится. При любом замысле надо пользоваться грамотной формой речи, и это касается всех авторов без исключения.

Comment: Вера, почитайте. [Деепричастный оборот](http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/deeprichastniy-oborot/?q=486&n=527)

Comment: У Горького здесь плохой стиль, звучит неграмотно:  "Она не ответила ему, задумчиво следя за игрой волн, взбегавших на берег, колыхая тяжелый баркас" (Горький).  У Пушкина, конечно, все хорошо: "Дом его всегда был полон гостями, готовыми тешить его барскую праздность (как?), разделяя шумные, а иногда буйные его увеселения (П у ш к и н. У Пушкина это обстоятельство образа действия, а у Горького - второе действие.

Comment: За галлицизмы серьёзным писателям двойка, а Vera — за XIX век.

Comment: @Vera почему это пример из п.2а не отнесён к п.2б? "рассматривая необходимо привлечь" - почему авторы считают что "рассматривая" относится к "необходимо"? очевидно же что "рассматривая" относится к "привлечь". доказывается просто: заменим "привлечь" на "привлечение": "рассматривая, необходимо привлечение" - очевидная ошибка. значит "рассматривая" относилось к глаголу "привлечь", который если заменить на существительное, то связь рушится. - т.е п.2б

Comment: @whyer "рассматривая" относится к составному сказуемому "необходимо привлечь" как единому целому. Доказательство: уберем предикативное наречие из составного сказуемого "необходимо привлечь" и получим "рассматривая, быстро привлечь" - очевидная ошибка. Пример отнесен к 2(а) ибо "привлечь документы (каким образом?) рассматривая вопрос" - явная чушь. Что это за  особый образ привлечения документов - "рассматривая вопрос"???

Comment: По поводу исходного вопроса, думаю что предложение грамматически некорректно. 2б здесь не проходит по причинам указанным в комментарии @Alex_ander

Comment: @user190920 понял, действительно "привлечь как? - рассматривая" - глупо.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение ***"Глядя на них, ему очень захотелось пить"*** не считается ошибочным, свидетельством чего служат похожие примеры в "Национальном корпусе русского языка":
***Обзаведись они вовремя шутами (надо хотя бы от дурака слышать правду), может быть, им удалось бы продержаться ещё некоторое время. [Фазиль Искандер. Тринадцатый подвиг Геракла (1966)];
2. Скрываясь в высокой траве, нам удалось добраться незамеченными до самой поляны. [Виталий Губарев. Трое на острове (1950-1960)];***

> ***Убедившись, что понять этого он не может, ему стало скучно (Л. Толстой).***
>
> ***Прочитав внимательно рассказ, мне думается, что редакторских поправок в нем нет (Горький).***
>
> Стоит, однако, отметить, что такие предложения не ощущаются как вполне правильные. В современном русском языке деепричастия главным образом сочетаются с теми безличными предложениями, которые включают инфинитив, но не включают указания на субъекта в форме дательного падежа. Это в основном предложения с модальными словами "можно", "нужно", "необходимо" и им подобные.

Comment: По сравнению со случаем в вопросе, оба примера безобидны. В первом примере нет деепричастного оборота (на его месте условный оборот, эквивалентный предложению "если бы они обзавелись...", не требущий того же производителя действия). Во втором примере, если изменить порядок слов, деепричастный оборот будет выполнять функцию обстоятельства образа действия: удалось добраться как(им способом)? - скрываясь в высокой траве (т.е. источник действия общий). В предложении же из вопроса такого нельзя сказать: смысл его не в том, что "ему хотелось пить, (при этом) глядя на них".

Comment: @Alex_ander  представил себе: позвольте мне полюбоваться вами во время моего пития - очень хочется!

Answer (score 0):

"Глядя на них, ему очень захотелось пить". Мне кажется, смысл фразы здесь, как раз, очень простой для понимания. Ему захотелось пить, потому что он смотрел на них. То есть он посмотрел на них, что вызвало в нем некие ассоциации и впоследствии желание пить.

Comment: А что насчет предложения: "Поглядев на них, ему очень захотелось пить". -- Не режет слух, нет?

Comment: Вроде бы не очень. Нужно смотреть общую стилистику текста. Если персонаж простой парень с фермы Техаса или Миннесоты, то подобные авторские слова, относящиеся к персонажу, могут быть вполне гармоничны. Если и вовсе сам персонаж их произносит, то вполне гармонично. Например: "Э... Ну я поглядел на них... Странники после песчаной бури. Ну вы понимаете... А идти в гости ко мне отказались. - Джон стряхнул солому с волос. - Ну, в общем, поглядев на них, мне очень захотелось пить. Я и ушел к себе на ферму".

Comment: Но здесь, возможно, будет лучше написать "...поглядев на них, я сам захотел пить" или "глядя на них, мне самому захотелось пить". Мне кажется, ваш пример "Поглядев на них, ему очень захотелось пить" не совсем благозвучный.