# Согласование с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, деепричастный-оборот

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, согласованы ли две части предложения? Корректно ли оно?

"Бросая первый взгляд на этот интерьер, сразу же ощущается безмятежная атмосфера и гармония."

Answer (score 4):

Нет, предложение составлено неверно: допущена ошибка в употреблении деепричастного оборота.

Правильно:
*Бросая первый взгляд на этот интерьер, сразу же **ощущаешь** безмятежную атмосферу и гармонию*.

Следует помнить, что действие, выражаемое деепричастием, может относиться только к действующему подлежащему.

Answer (score 3):

Да, предложение **требует перестройки**.

Конструкции такого типа характерны для французского языка и называются галлицизмами, они встречались в прозе XIX века, например: "**Проезжая на возвратном пути в первый раз весною знакомую березовую рощу**, у меня голова закружилась и забилось сердце от смутного сладкого ожидания" (И.С. Тургенев).

Варианты замены могут быть различными, например: **При первом взгляде на этот интерьер** сразу же ощущается безмятежная атмосфера и гармония.

Comment: К счастью, у Тургенева это речь персонажа - или у него такое в авторской речи и в письмах встречается?

Comment: В "Практической стилистике" сказано, что  раньше  "неправильные" конструкции допускались. У Толстого:  "...убедившись, что понять этого он не может, ему стало скучно".  У Горького: "Прочитав внимательно рассказ, мне думается, что редакторских поправок в нем нет".

Comment: А вообще говоря,  встречаются  неоднозначные варианты с деепричастными оборотами, это касается прежде всего БЕЗЛИЧНЫХ предложений.  Интересная дискуссия  была на форуме http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402/Деепричастный-оборот-в-безличном-предложении-при-инфинитиве