# Взглянув на дождь за окном, мне стало грустно

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Почему это предложение неправильно?

> Взглянув на дождь за окном, мне стало грустно.

Comment: Точка всегда за кавычками.

Comment: Улучшенный якобы варьянт: "Ну можно догадаться что за окно взглянул тот, кому грустно стало".

Comment: Пару дней назад был похожий вопрос:
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426458/Согласование-с-деепричастным-оборотом

Comment: @Alex_ander действительно))) Парами ходят. Но понимаете, автор, видимо, имеет затруднение с конкретной фразой, поэтому отсылать к просто "похожему" не совсем правильно. должно быть совсем уж "один в один". А там случай более очевидный. "ощущается атмосфера" - это двусоставное предложение с явным агенсом (производителем действия), который столь же явно не совпадает с агенсом деепричастия. У нас не так, "мне"  и "взглянув" - это вроде как про одно одно лицо, в том и сложность. Не стоит переадресовывать,

Comment: Дело в том, что я читал тот похожий вопрос, но эта фраза была пропущена, хотя другие обсуждались. Я просто понял, что в деепричастном обороте должно быть существительное, если проще понимать. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Надо:

*Взглянув на дождь за окном, я загрустил.*

Или:

*При взгляде на дождь за окном мне стало грустно.*

[**Разберем основные типы ошибок при употреблении деепричастных оборотов.**](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200403608)

> 1. *Подходя к этой комнате, за дверью раздались странные звуки.
>
> Основное действие совершают звуки (звуки раздались). Добавочное
>   действие совершает другой субъект (например, он или я). Значит,
>   ошибочность предложения в том, что у двух действий (основного и
>   добавочного) разные производители. Исправить можно приблизительно так:
>   Когда я подходил к этой комнате, то услышал, что за дверью раздались
>   странные звуки.
>
> 2. *Выйдя на улицу, мне стало холодно.
>
> Данное предложение безличное, в нем не может быть подлежащего. А
>   значит, нет и субъекта действия (на субъект действия указывает
>   дополнение мне). В таких предложениях нельзя употреблять деепричастный
>   оборот. Исправить можно так: Когда я вышел на улицу, мне стало
>   холодно.
>
> В безличных предложениях можно употребить деепричастный оборот в том
>   случае, если главный член выражен инфинитивом: Устраиваясь на ночлег,
>   следует выбрать место посуше. В данном предложении подлежащего нет. Но
>   у основного и добавочного действий («выбрать» и «устраиваясь») один и
>   тот же субъект действия («вы выбираете» и «вы устраиваетесь»).
>
> 3. *Приехав в Москву, машина будет разгружена.
>
> Данное предложение – страдательная конструкция. Значит, производитель
>   действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного
>   деепричастием, не совпадают. Подлежащее называет объект основного
>   действия и субъект действия, названного деепричастием. Проще говоря,
>   приедет в Москву машина, а разгружать ее будет кто-то, а не она сама
>   себя. Исправить можно так: Когда машина приедет в Москву, она будет
>   разгружена.

Comment: Третий пример - спорный: в обоих случаях грамматический производитель действия - машина, а не шофёр или закадровые грузчики. Она "сама себя высекает", будет (это её бытие и судьба) разгружена или  "разгрузится" (беспилотная у неё разгрузка или нет) . Вот если "приехав в Москву, машину разгрузят", машина даже ехать не сможет, а грузчикам придётся попутешествовать.

Comment: @Alex_ander Позволю себе заметить, что здесь все примеры - "не в кассу". Вопрос-то не в том, знает ли G.А.  правила на все случае жизни, а есть ли хоть одно, которое нужно спрашивающему. Тому самому, на которого она сорвалась в первой же строчке.

Comment: Что касается третьего "примера" (безотносительно к вопросу), он не то что спорен, он абсолютно правилен грамматически. Непонятно, что его заставило сюда поместить, кроме разве слепого следования формальным "запоминалкам". Здесь производитель действия - машина. И то что действие это "страдательное" (уже не школьный подход, имхо) никого не должно пугать. Вспомогательный глагол "будет" согласуется по лицу и числу с подлежащим, значит деепричастие может быть "привязано" к действию и его производителю.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае действия глагола и деепричастия разнесены во времени. Из-за отсутствия подлежащего и *одновременно* "обстоятельственной" (а не причинной, как здесь) связи между глаголом и деепричастием последние не могут быть отнесены к общему производителю действия. Как уже отмечалось, для выражения задуманного смысла нужно вводить подлежащее:

> Взглянув на дождь за окном, я загрустил.

Значит ли это, что подобное безличное предложение с деепричастным оборотом и упоминанием "меня" невозможно? Нет. Если деепричастный оборот раскрывает обстоятельство действия глагола, нет проблем. Но смысл будет иным, чем в вашем предложении (причина "грусти" - за пределами сказанного):

> Мне оставалось грустить, поглядывая на дождь за окном.

Comment: *В данном случае действия глагола и деепричастия разнесены во времени*  - не поэтому. "Разнести по времени" деепричастие и сказуемое - это дело не хитрое и ни на чем не скажется. *Столкнувшись с подобной ошибкой в прошло, её следует запомнить, чтобы не повторять в будущем* - выбираете любое время, фраза грамматически корректна.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexandrBakhta В современном русском языке деепричастие (взглянув) не может существовать самостоятельно, в отрыве от основного глагола. Деепричастие просто раскрывает обстоятельства его действия. Поэтому действующее лицо глагола и деепричастия должны совпадать.

В вашей фразе этого нет. Кто взглянул за окно и что "стало грустно"? Тут вообще нет действующих лиц. Ну можно догадаться, что за окно взглянул тот, кому грустно стало. Но "стало грустно кому" - это не действующее лицо, это безличная форма глагола.

Если поменять на "Взглянув на дождь за окном, **я** стал грустен" (это максимально близко к исходному), все становится на свои места.

Comment: Согласен. Запятые только поправьте, а то опять начнется.

Comment: @slava1947 Да. Спасибо.