# Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастный-оборот

Насколько корректно данное предложение с деепричастным оборотом в безличном предложении:
**Глядя на эту девушку, в моей голове всплыло «жертва».**

Вызывает затруднение вторая часть.

Comment: Читайте классиков. "Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа."  (Чехов. Жалобная книга) https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426558/%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 3):

Предложение не отвечает норме.

**Редактирование:**

При взгляде на эту девушку в моей голове всплыло –  "жертва".

Тире обозначает паузу на месте пропущенного "слово". Тогда предложение можно считать двусоставным.

**Справочный материал**  [Розенталь. XLVIII. ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНЫЕ СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm)

**Правило:**

1) Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится, как правило, **к подлежащему данного предложения**. Если же производитель действия, обозначенного глаголом-сказуемым, и производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, **не совпадают**, употребление деепричастного оборота **стилистически ошибочно**, например: «Переходя через рельсы, стрелочника оглушил неожиданный свисток паровоза» (переходя относится к стрелочнику, а оглушил – к свистку).

2) Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота **в страдательной конструкции,** так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана».

**Исключения**

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия **подлежащего**:

1)       **если производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, совпадает с производителем действия**, обозначенного **другой глагольной формой** (инфинитивом, причастием, деепричастием), например: Автору **было предложено внести** в рукопись дополнения, **учитывая изменения**, происшедшие в жизни общества за последнее время;

2)       **в безличном предложении при инфинитиве,** например: **Приходилось работать** в трудных условиях, **не имея** в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.

**Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива**, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно, например. «Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно»; «Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в серьезной доработке».