# Верно ли построено предложение с деепричастным оборотом?

Tags: синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

> Вчитываясь в рассказы Чехова, можно за видимой простотой находить
>   глубину смысла и сложность художественного построения.

Все ли здесь верно? Я не вижу в этом предложении субъекта, к которому бы относился деепричастный оборот, однако на *Решу ЕГЭ* ошибки в построении деепричастного оборота здесь нет.

Comment: Полное предложение выглядит так: _Рассказы Чехова коротки, но каждый раз, вчитываясь в них, можно за видимой простотой находить глубину смысла и сложность художественного построения._ http://sobolev.franklang.ru/index.php/konets-xix-veka/70-v-kataev-slozhnost-prostoty

Comment: [Здесь](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=12453) это самое задание, но без необходимого подлежащего, точнее, оно встроено в оборот.

Comment: Конечно, ноги, которые опомнились и схватили рюкзак, смотрится тоже не очень красиво, но здесь хоть что-то есть. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение на современный слух несколько тяжеловесно построено, но формальной ошибки в нем действительно нет.

> то самое задание, но без необходимого подлежащего, точнее, оно
>   встроено в оборот.

Здесь есть подразумеваемый или скрытый субъект действия, причем важно, что он один и тот же для самого-глагола сказуемого и для деепричастного оборота: кто вчитывается, тот и может найти. Такие конструкции допустимы, хотя и ограниченно.

Вот тут подробно и даже в историческом преломлении: 
[Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении при инфинитиве?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402)

(++)
А вообще Владимир Борисович Катаев плохого не посоветует. Уж он-то, авторитетнейший специалист по творчеству Чехова, историю про подъезжавшую к станции шляпу знает не понаслышке.
(+++)
Вспомнить про чеховедческую сущность В. Б. Катаева меня отчасти заставила Марина Королева, еще полтора десятилетия назад именем Чехова активно боровшаяся как раз с подобными оборотами.
https://rg.ru/2005/09/30/deeprichastia.html

Вот ведь как бывает: главный чеховед страны попал под "чеховскую" раздачу Марины Александровны. Интересно, что бы она на эту фразу сказала?!

Answer (score 2):

Это предложение о потенциально возможных действиях неопределённого лица (я, он, ограниченная группа лиц, любой), которое можно себе представить. Важно, чтобы действия, выраженные деепричастием и глаголом, относились к одному и тому же производителю. Здесь это выполняется: "может находить" именно тот, кто "вчитывается". Поэтому предложение построено верно.

Answer (score 1):

Вчитываясь в рассказы Чехова, **можно** за видимой простотой **находить** глубину смысла и сложность художественного построения.

Здесь **безличное предложение с инфинитивом,** в этом случае можно использовать деепричастный оборот. И по смыслу ситуация понятна: у любого субъекта есть возможность.

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

В ряде случаев **возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:**

2)       **в безличном предложении при инфинитиве,** например: **Приходилось работать** в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.