# Употребление деепричастного оборота в безличном предложении

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Корректно ли употребление деепричастного оборота в следующем предложении:
 "В борту судна появилась дырка, а потом палубу перед надстройкой выдуло фонтаном огня, разбрасывая пиратов и роняя лебедку"?

Comment: Вот здесь имеется полезная информация: _Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении при инфинитиве._ https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402/Деепричастный-оборот-в-безличном-предложении-при-инфинитиве

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли использовать деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении?  В современном языке картина складывается примерно такая: **можно, но осторожно.**

Существуют **два фактора**, которые нужно учитывать: **(1) инфинитив и (2) наличие падежной формы, указывающей на субъект действия.** При этом инфинитив желательно иметь, а падежная форма должна отсутствовать.

Если инфинитив имеется, то указанием на субъект можно пренебречь (вариант разрешенный), например: *Надо всё проверить, учитывая новые данные. **Мне** надо всё проверить, учитывая новые данные.*

**Если инфинитива нет,** то конструкция переходит в сомнительную (серую) зону:  она уже не строго литературная, а только допускается. И тогда вопрос о субъекте становится важным, например: 
(1) *Читая это, делается грустно* (допустимая конструкция с общим суждением и неясным производителем действия). 
(2)*Читая это, **мне** делается грустно* (нет, этот вариант нельзя использовать).

2) *В борту судна появилась дырка, а потом палубу перед надстройкой **выдуло фонтаном огня**, разбрасывая пиратов и роняя лебедку.*

Инфинитива нет, а указание на субъект действия есть (**сразу два минуса**).

Вот **у Пелевина** можно найти пример без инфинитива и без указания субъекта (вариант допускается):

*Раздался знакомый наждачный звук, и какая-то невидимая сила мгновенно расплющила нескольких орков ― их словно **выдуло** из доспехов, **превратив в красный пар**, а сами доспехи стали похожи н*а выглаженную огромным утюгом одежду, плоско дымящуюся на земле. [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)]

3) Что можно сделать, если автор хочет **сохранить деепричастную конструкцию?** Придется перейти к  двусоставному предложению:

*В борту судна появилась дырка,  а потом **фонтан огня  выдул** палубу перед надстройкой, разбрасывая пиратов и роняя лебедку.*

Comment: Интересно, а кто придумал такой термин ***серая** зона?*

Comment: Вам нравится? Ну не я, конечно. Это из Грамматики:  Самая строгая концепция, представленная в [Грамматика 1980], признает нормативными только деепричастие, связанное с именительным падежом субъекта, и деепричастие в обобщенно-личных предложениях, другие конструкции остаются в «СЕРОЙ» зоне (не рекомендуемые). http://rusgram.ru/Деепричастие#72

Comment: Ну да, нравится. Хотя бы тем, что для таких случаев можно ловко "вынуть из кармана" такой термин. =)

Comment: Вот и мне понравился, и был использован как раз для этой цели.

Comment: :) Кстати, Sharon, а можете объяснить запятую в последнем своём комментарии?
 Ведь даже если считать его ССП с опущенными подлежащими, сами подлежащие-то совпадают (т. е. оно общее), значит, это не ССП, верно? А какая ещё причина для запятой?

Comment: Второе предложение в составе ССП неполное,  субъект действия мы восстанавливаем по первому предложению. У двух первых предложений одинаковый субъект действия, а подлежащие могут быть разными. Запятая не ставится, если мы будем считать три сказуемых однородными, но это не так. Нам пришлось разделить их на группы, так как второе и третье сказуемые образуют единую конструкцию

Comment: Спасибо, а можете пояснить насчёт разных подлежащих? (И ещё не по теме, но, пользуясь случаем, спрошу: мне никто не отвечает на вопрос про "представляешь", может, Вы знаете, что сказать по этому поводу, и ответите, как будет возможность?)

Comment: Я имела в виду, что Марья, она - это разные подлежащие в двух разных простых предложениях в составе ССП, но при этом они обозначают одно действующее лицо. Второй Ваш вопрос я видела. Он чисто интонационного характера, и слово это говорится с разной интонацией. Я могу только свое мнение обозначить, чуть позже наверное.

Comment: Какая Марья?! Я говорил про запятую в этом предложении: *Вот и мне понравился, и был использован как раз для этой цели.* Спасибо заранее, что обозначите мнение!

Comment: Да, надо точно указывать предложение, а то будем говорить о разных вещах.  Запятую я ставлю по интонации, обозначая две ситуации, разделенные паузой. Тогда у меня два неполных предложения в составе ССП. Этому также способствует разная форма сказуемых (активный и пассивный залог). Правила позволяют автору делать выбор между однородными сказуемыми и сложным предложением. Также я могу посчитать И присоединительным, а не соединительным союзом.Так что разные есть возможности для того, чтобы поставить запятую и объяснить ее.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо за объяснения!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, без действующего лица деепричастный оборот здесь неуместен. Если действующее лицо *фонтан огня,* тогда надо превратить деепричастия в причастия:

> *В борту судна появилась дырка, а потом палубу перед надстройкой выдуло фонтаном огня, разбрасывающим пиратов и роняющим лебедку.*

Answer (score 0):

Здесь ошибка, редакторами пропущенная. Вопрос только, к какому типу ошибок отнести: грамматических, стилистических или логических. Есть подозрение, что тут все три.

Грамматически здесь случай спорный. Вроде бы и можно, поскольку абстакный производитель действия у глагола и деепричастия совпадает ([нечто (у автора - ракета)] выдуло, разбрасывая), хотя  смотрится все-таки коряво.
Хуже другое. "Роняя лебедку" - это как? Стремительным домкратом? Как ракета может ***уронить лебедку***, если она её никогда в руках не держала?!

Варианты правки я не рискну предлагать, ибо не поможет без понимания того, что такм на кого чего уронил.  Вообще, это конечно личное мнение, но Валерия Большакова к мастерам изысканного слова отнести трудно. Автор явно не испытывает желания выражаться изысканным слогом.