# Может ли деепричастие быть связано с существительным, выступающим в роли сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые, существительные, деепричастия

Пример: "Хлеб, будучи основой рациона, всему голова". То есть "будучи" здесь описывает дополнительное действие по отношение к основному "действию": тому, что "хлеб ... – голова".

Comment: Не может. Вы грамматику этой фразы сами разбирали - или подсказал кто?

Comment: Я спорю с одним человеком, который утверждает, что данное предложение соответствует правилам русского языка. Я считаю, что не соответствует, но на всякий случай решил посоветоваться – вдруг я что-то упускаю. Так что да, "подсказал кто".

Comment: Естествено, что ошибаетесь. Причем дважды. Во-первых, вам надо было так и спросить, соответствует оно ли "правилам" (вернее - нормам грамматики). А во-вторых потому, что грамматика, вами изложенная, совершенно надуманная.   Ладно, отвечу... Вопрос уж без меня переделают.

Answer (score 1):

> утверждает, что данное предложение соответствует правилам русского
> языка

Да, вполне соответствует. В этой части я с ним полностью согласен.

> Счастлив ты, мой друг, будучи в состоянии облегчать судьбу несчастных.
> [Д. И. Фонвизин. Недоросль (1782)]

Грамматика тут немного другая, но глагола-сказуемого в явном виде тоже нет.

Вот что касается идеи о том, что деепричастие может относиться к подлежащему или вообще к чему-то еще, помимо сказуемого... Никак не могу с эти согласиться.

Да, тут есть некая сложность, в том, что в школе приучают считать "всему голова" сказуемым. Но по формальным правилам грамматику надо трактовать как составное именное с опущенным глаголом-связкой.
То есть:
"Хлеб, будучи основой рациона, [есть] всему голова"

Вот к этому самому "есть" и относится деепричастие.

(+) ====
В роэтической речи иногда встречаются примеры деепричастия, относящегося к то ли к существительному, то ли вообще к целому предложению:

*Немного красного вина,

Немного солнечного мая -

И, тоненький бисквит ломая,

Тончайших пальцев белизна.*

(Мандельштам)

Вот тут идея об опущенном глаголе-связке не поможет. Но такие форму и не считаются нормативными.

Comment: "Грамматика тут немного другая, но глагола-сказуемого в явном виде тоже нет."

Я и не сомневался в том, что деепричастие может быть связано со сказуемым, являющимся кратким прилагательным. Аналогичный пример: "Не окончив ВУЗ, я должен был устроиться на работу". Однако мой вопрос предполагает сказуемое-существительное, а не сказуемое-прилагательное.

Comment: "Вот что касается идеи о том, что деепричастие может относиться к подлежащему или вообще к чему-то еще, помимо сказуемого... Никак не могу с эти согласиться."

Деепричастие может относиться только к сказуемому, однозначно. Я был неточен, раз показалось, что я считаю иначе.

Comment: В целом, конечно, большое спасибо за ответ. Буду размышлять.

Comment: @JKlen *к чему относится деепричастие во фразе вождение, будучи пьяным?* - к грамматическим ошибкам.

Comment: *Деепричастия очень близки по функционалу к наречиям* - а это к ошибкам фактическим.

Comment: Согласен с JKlen. Недавно проскакивал показательный вопрос, ставший уже классикой форума, обязательной к изучению: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402. Вот примеры наречного деепричастия у Пушкина "Дом его всегда был полон гостями, готовыми тешить его барскую праздность (как?), разделяя шумные, а иногда буйные его увеселения". А следующий пример уже у Горького: "Она не ответила ему, задумчиво следя за игрой волн, взбегавших на берег, колыхая тяжелый баркас"