# Использование деепричастия

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

Не знаю, как так вышло, но это предложение вызвало какой-то ступор:

"Один раз познав тепло, в котором нуждался, его уже трудно будет забыть".

Не нужно редактировать формулировку в целом, пожалуйста. Если не ошибаюсь, деепричастие неправильно использовано, верно? Потому что:

"Один раз познав тепло, в котором нуждался, ТЕБЕ его уже трудно будет забыть". А лицо должно быть в именительном падеже.

"Один раз познав тепло, в котором нуждался, ТЫ уже не сможешь его забыть".

Не знаю, в чем дело, но хотелось бы уточнить. Может, там исключение какое есть. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну... можно по-другому синтаксический разбор пострить и получить корректное предложение:

```
Забыть тепло, познав его один раз, уже будет трудно.
Познав тепло один раз, забыть его уже будет трудно.
```

Здесь деепричастие относится к основному действию **забыть** в неопределенной форме. Поэтому все корректно. См также пару статей про деепричастия, чтобы лучше разбираться в этой теме

[Обсуждение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

[Обзорный экскурс в деепричастие](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)