# О слове «отдышавшись»

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастия, части-речи, деепричастия

В книге встретился такой оборот: "отдышавшись, мне удалось выйти".
Интуиция подсказывает, что глагол не согласуется с причастием, но каким правилом это объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

***Отдышавшись, мне удалось выйти*** — в этой конструкции нет ни причастия, ни причастного оборота.
[*Отдышавшись*](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) — это деепричастие (что сделав?) прошедшего времени от глагола "отдышаться", а соответствующее причастие — *отдышавшийся*.

Использование такого вида оборотов все-таки допускается.
Об этом имеются разъяснения на нашем форуме, [*здесь*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417402/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5) ("Деепричастный оборот в безличном предложении при инфинитиве").

Имеются и примеры:
*А другому оставалось утереться и, отдышавшись от обиды, принять валидол* (Г. Я. Бакланов. Жизнь, подаренная дважды);
*Немного отдышавшись, мне удалось сконцентрироваться на дальней стене, к которой примыкал уступ* (Егор Аянский. Кай 5);
*Едва отдышавшись, мне не удалось подобрать мата, чтобы выпустить пар* ( Руслан де Хан. Последний патрон Чехова).

[Совершенно же правильным является такое оформление: *отдышавшись, я вышел.*]